# Android retrofit 2 send array as field

Tags: arrays, mapping, retrofit2

```
 @FormUrlEncoded    
 @POST("mobile/order")
 Call<OrderResult> orederTaxi(
        @Field("user_id") Integer user_id,
        @Field("driver_id") Integer driver_id,
        @Field ("locations") List<String> location);
```

retrofit 2 maps the elements of array and create key_value pairs like this `driver_id: 8

```
locations: 40.7830904,43.861694

locations: 40.789281071949176,43.8663412258029

locations: 40.79531973066005,43.86150989681482

locations: 40.79855839824006,43.85658267885446
```

but I have to send as one jsonArray, like:  `

```
locations:[
 "40.7830904,43.861694",
 "40.789281071949176,43.86634122580292",
 "40.79531973066005,43.86150989681482"
]
```